# Как работать с независимыми клонами репозиториев в IntelliJ-IDEA-подобных IDE?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, контроль-версий

В данном вопросе мы рассматриваем работу с системами контроля версий **без использования консоли** средсвами IntelliJ IDEA-подобных IDE (WebStrom, PHPStorm и другие).

Допустим, я разместил шаблон проекта на удалённом репозитории. На основе этого проекта нужно будет создавать новые проекты. В чём проблема?

Если на стартовом экране IDE кликнуть кнопку-ссылку "Checkout from Version Control", внести изменения в файлах, а потом попытаться выполнить push, то push произойдёт в тот же репозиторий, из которого я сделал checkout. А надо - в репозиторий не шаблона, а в новый репозиторий проекта. Я не нашёл, где указать новый репозиторий.

Вероятно, нужно сначала создать копию проекта на сайте, где находится удалённый репозиторий (GitHub, ну или я использую BitBucket). Опять же: как? Можно, конечно, сделать fork, на данная функция предназначена для модификации уже существующих проектов, а не для создания проекта на основе шаблонов...

Comment: Надо начинать не с checkout, а c VCS->Git->Clone

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Попробовал. И так и так придётся в явном виде указывать новый удалённый репозиторий.

Comment: А что, в принятом вами ответе не надо указывать в явном виде удалённый репозиторий? Машина сама угадает его адрес?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Нужно. Если кто-нибудь даст ответ, где не нужно - поставлю галочку этому ответу. Машина, конечно, сама угадать адрес нового репозитория не может, поэтому максимум, чего можно достигнуть - это только указать URL нового репозитория без лишних операций по удалению информации о старом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сначала создать пустой репозиторий под новый проект.

Далее:

- делаете клон из старого проекта
- В меню выбираете `VCS` / `Git`/ `Remotes`
- В появившемся окне `+` и добавляете свой новый репозиторий
- Удаляете из списка старый репозиторий
- Меню `VCS` / `Git` / `Push` на кнопке выбрать `Force push`

файлы пойдут в новый репозиторий